# Can Jackson's node structure be used to write XML?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm trying to set up code to create a node tree using jackson which can then be used to write either JSON or XML. I can get the JSON working, but I was hoping to get it outputting XML this way as well.

My example tree would look like this:

```
XmlMapper NodeMap = new XmlMapper();

ObjectNode rootNode = NodeMap.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Examples");
currentNode
        .put("Puppy", TRUE)
        .put("Apple", 2)
        .put("Jet", "Li");
currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Single");
currentNode.put("One", 1);
```

Using this tree I can use

```
String xml = rootNode.toString();
```

to get

```
{"Examples":{"Puppy":true,"Apple":2,"Jet":"Li"},"Single":{"One":1}}
```

which shows the tree has been built correctly, but I've been hoping it would output XML because I'm attaching the tree to an XmlMapper. That alone doesn't seem to be enough, unfortunately.

I know I can take another object and do something like

```
XmlMapper XMap = new XmlMapper();
XMap.writeValue(new File(writePath), objectToBeConverted);
```

to get XML but I'm looking to use the nodetree above and .writevalue doesn't seem to work with the nodes.

How would I take the above tree and output (to a String or a file) as XML? Is it possible or am I out of luck with this method?

EDIT: I'm using Jackson version 2.9.2 
EDIT2: Turns out I had multiple versions of jackson overlapping, as andrii mentions in the comments under his answer.

Comment: Should be #6 in this tutorial, your code looks right though. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: ".writevalue doesn't seem to work with the nodes." What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I get a compile error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeStartObject(Ljava/lang/Object;)V at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode.serialize(ObjectNode.java:290)

Comment: @Alexander Please [edit] your question to include the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: Also, what is `objectToBeConverted`? Do you mean `rootNode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `writeValueAsString`, e.g.:

```
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ObjectNode currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Examples");
    currentNode
            .put("Puppy", true)
            .put("Apple", 2)
            .put("Jet", "Li");
    currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Single");
    currentNode.put("One", 1);

    String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);
```

In addition, I think you're using incompatible dependency version. I was able to reproduce your error having jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.2 and old jackson-core:2.6.7. Make sure you'r using compatible versions for jackson-dataformat-xml dependencies.

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's code that calls `writeValue()` other than writing to a string in memory vs writing to a file on disk?

Comment: `writeValueAsString` just because op is hopping to see xml in `String xml` variable. But, yeah, `writeValue` works fine if you need to write result to file.

Comment: mapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode) gives me a compile error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeStartObject(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode.serialize(ObjectNode.java:290)

This is the same error I would get from 
XMap.writeValue(new File(writePath), rootNode); that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: what version of `jackson-dataformat-xml` are you using? I use 2.9.8: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.9.8

Comment: I'm using 2.9.2. Is that far enough back to exclude this functionality?

Comment: @Alexander I think you'r using incompatible dependency version. I was able to reproduce your error having `jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.2` and old `jackson-core:2.6.7`. Make sure you'r using compatible versions for `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependencies.

Comment: The version incompatibility/inconsistency was the problem in the end, as you mention in your latest comment. I've gone ahead and accepted your answer and edited your comment into the answer itself (awaiting peer review) since that's what helped me fix the issue.